# Scroll bar disappearing in responsive design when screen size goes beyound 1280 px

Tags: css, html, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using one css design and it works perfectly in full size browser but whenever screen size is reduced below 1280 px in width scroll bar goes missing and responsiveness in design gets frozen to that frame so user can not view complete site, can not scroll when on mobile devices or after reducing browser screen size. Request to please help with that. Below is the link to site where this problem is occurring

http://goo.gl/VzVmTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your body overflow to hidden, once it gets to a specific width, so once you need the scroll, as soon as the browser renders your CSS, it will assume the overflow:hidden attribute thus removing your scrolling capabilities.

This happens on line 315 of your irms_default.css:

```
@media screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1180px){
    body{overflow:hidden;text-align:center;}
```

If you really need to apply a hidden overflow, try applying it only to the elements that need it to prevent such issues. A 'body' with a hidden overflow should exist only on static single page designs, to ensure the best of the user's experience.